# Can't open script file in SQL Server 2008 R2 job

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I try to open a SQL script file on my local machine from the SQL Server Job configuration window, I get the following error:

> Access to the path 'C:\temp\tbl_MiscInfo.sql' is denied. (mscorlib)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
>   share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
>   secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at System.IO.File.Open(String path,
>   FileMode mode)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.TSQLJobSubSystemDefinition.openFile_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

To be clear, here is a screen shot of the action I'm trying to perform:

[image]

This seems to be a permissions issue, but nothing I try seems to work.

The sqlagent on my machine is using a user that has admin privileges, I've given the login for the job a user credential that has admin privileges, and I've set the "run as user" option to a user mapped to the login with admin privileges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your intention to have the job read from the file each time? If not, why don't you just open the .sql command and paste the code into the command window?

Comment: My intention is to have it read from the file each time it runs because I plan to update the files contents.

Comment: When you click Open... this has nothing to do with SQL agent, the job owner, etc. It has to do with the user you are running Management Studio as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. When you click "Open..." all it does is take the contents of the file you specify and dump them into the Command: dialog - this means the script is static and will not reflect any changes you make after you save the job.

If you want it to use a .sql file at runtime you'll need to look at using a CmdExec step type (where you can call SQLCmd outside the SQL Server process) or a PowerShell command. Alternatively, the job step could use xp_cmdshell to read in the contents of the .sql script (using the type command) and execute the contents as dynamic SQL.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work the way I was hoping, I'll try one of the other routes you suggested. Still, you would think management studio would be running under my user, and would thus have permissions to open the file. Anyhow, thanks!

Comment: You'll have to run procmon (or at least the feature set that used to be found in filemon) or similar to determine who is trying to access the file and what is causing the error. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645